# Sqlite - More columns containing 1 data or one column containing all of it?

Tags: sqlite

Lets say we have a random table. What is the better choice for performance?

1. To add four columns called "a", "b", "c", "d" to that table  OR
2. To add just one column named "data" where I can store the strings that contain all of the data in these four columns -> "a;b;c;d" (which is not a problem because I can explode the string)

Probably a stupid question, but I don't want to have too many columns. But if it is bad for performance then I won't do it

Comment: for example, instead of having 3 different columns "x", "y" and "z" -> "x;y;z" in one column

Comment: This depends on the actual kind of data, and what operations you will do on it. You get the best performance when you do not store the data at all, but that is probably not appropriate in your application …